# Trying to simulate the clicking of a button with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, forms, greasemonkey, form-submit

I'm trying to write a greasemonkey script that updates inventory for a collection of items through the browser. To do this I need to autofill a few forms and simulate a mouseclick on the submission button. I have the forms filling out fine, but I'm stuck on the button submission.

Here is the HTML for the button I am trying to simulate clicking

```
<input type="submit" value="Find" style="" name="process-form" onclick="imhocaller.value='find-resources-page.left'; imhoaction.value='process-form';">
```

I tried doing something like this, but haven't had any luck.

```
document.getElementsByName('process-form').submit();
```

I can post more code if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also dispatch a custom click event via most recent browsers and "fire" an `onclick` event in IE. This is a recent feature that allows tons of control over events.

```
var button = document.getElementById("test");
button.onclick = function()
{
    alert("event was dispatched on me");      
}
if(document.createEvent)
{
    var click = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    click.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    button = document.getElementById("test");
    button.dispatchEvent(click);
    button.focus();
}else if(document.documentElement.fireEvent)
{
    button = document.getElementById("test");
    button.fireEvent("onclick");
    button.focus();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWyp7/3/

Do note that you need to listen for the event before dispatching it.

Comment: Thank you! I imagine this is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out. needed to use .click() instead of .submit().
I also needed to add the [0] as Georgy suggested.

```
document.getElementsByName('process-form')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this document.getElementsByName('process-form')**[0]**.submit();

UPD: Right! Must be .click() and not .submit()

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to work either. Thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

Here you try to submit a input, you have to submit the form. So if you  tag as an id of #myForm you need to do : `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use `.trigger( "submit" )` in JQuery.